# Optimize code to sum variables by group in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, aggregate

I have the following toy data:

| Gene | cell1 | cell2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | 1 | 12 |
| Gene1 | 9 | 1 |
| Gene2 | 0 | 0 |
| Gene3 | 6 | 11 |

```
df <- data.frame(
    Gene= c("Gene1","Gene1","Gene2","Gene3"),
    gene_1 = c(1,9,0,6),
    gene_2 = c(12,1,0,11)
)
```

I want to group by gene name and sum the value of other columns if they are duplicated.

| Gene | cell1 | cell2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | 10 | 13 |
| Gene2 | 0 | 0 |
| Gene3 | 6 | 11 |

I use the following code to complete this task, but I cannot use it for my actual data because it is quite large and the following code is very slow.

```
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(Gene) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Is there other, less computationally expensive, ways to complete this task? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group. You have a specific answer for large data sets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686783/13460602).

Comment: and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61478862/13460602)

Answer (score 2):

Try `rowsums` which is specialized in summing up per group.

```
rowsum(df[-1], df[,1])
#      gene_1 gene_2
#Gene1     10     13
#Gene2      0      0
#Gene3      6     11
```